# kivy button event in For loop

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am looking to create buttons in a for loop. my problem is on the on_press property. 
I read stuff about closures (if that's the problem). But I did not really understand.

a little help.thx sorry for english.

the .py code:

```
import kivy
import webbrowser


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label, Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

word_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']


class LoopButton(BoxLayout):
    def aff(self):
        for w in word_list:
            url = 'https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + w
            button = Button(text= w, on_press= webbrowser.open(url))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoopButton()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and the .kv

```
    #:kivy 1.10

<LoopButton>
    Label:
        text: 'TEST'
    Button:
        id: 'affiche'
        text: 'afficher'
        on_press: root.aff()
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

`on_press=webbrowser.open(url)` will open the webbrowser when instantiating/creating Button widget.

## Solution

Create a `on_press` callback method and create the url in the callback method

### Snippet

```
class LoopButton(BoxLayout):
    def aff(self):
        for w in word_list:
            button = Button(text=w, on_press=self.open_webbrowser)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)

    def open_webbrowser(self, instance):
        url = 'https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + instance.text
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

[Event dispatcher » bind()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind)

> In general, ***property callbacks*** are called with ***2 arguments*** (the object
> and the property’s new value) and ***event callbacks*** with ***one argument***
> (the object).

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Answer (score 1):

on_press wants you to pass a callback, and you are passing the evaluated function to it, so there are 3 possible solutions.

1. Use `functools.partial`:

   ```
   import kivy
   import webbrowser
   from functools import partial
   ...

   class LoopButton(BoxLayout):
       def aff(self):
           for w in word_list:
               url = 'https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + w
               button = Button(text= w, on_press=partial(webbrowser.open, url))
               ...
   ```
2. Use `lambda`:

   ```
   button = Button(text= w, on_press= lambda *args, url=url: webbrowser.open(url))
   ```
3. Create a callback:

   ```
   class LoopButton(BoxLayout):
       def aff(self):
           for w in word_list:
               button = Button(text= w, on_press=self.callback)
               self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)

       def callback(self, instance):
           url = 'https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + instance.text
           webbrowser.open(url)
   ```